# Show that if $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$, then the normal closure $N'$ of $L:M$ is contained in the normal closure $N$ of $L:K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, alternative-proof

I'm trying to show in an easy manner that if $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$, then the normal closure $N'$ of $L:M$ is contained in the normal closure $N$ of $L:K$.

My book uses the following definition of normal closure: $N$ is a normal closure of $L:K$ if $N$ is a finite extension of $K$ containing $L$ such that:

$1)$ $N:K$ is normal, and

$2)$ If $L \subseteq M \subseteq N$ and $M:K$ is normal then $M=N$.

---

The proof I know is the following:

Let $A=${$a_1, ..., a_r$} be a basis for $L:M$ such that $1=a_1 \in A$, and

let $B=${$b_1, ..., b_s$} be a basis for $M:K$ such that $1=b_1 \in B$, then

$AB = $ {$ab:a \in A, b \in B$} $=C =${$c_1, ..., c_n$} is a basis for $L:K$ such that $A \cup B \subseteq C$.

Let $p_i$ be the minimal polynomial of $a_i$ over $M$ and let $f_j$ be the minimal polynomial of $c_j$ over $K$, then $N'$ is the splitting field of $ \prod ^n _{i=1} p_i$ over $M$, while $N$ is the splitting field of $ \prod ^n _{j=1} f_j$ over $K$.

Let $x$ be any zero of $p_i$. Such $p_i$ is the minimal polynomial of $a_i$ over $M$, notice that $a_i \in C$, consider then the minimal polynomial $f_j$ of $c_j = a_i$ over $K$. In $M[t]$ we have $p_iq=f_j$, so that all the zeroes of $p_i$ are zeroes of $f_j$. But all the zeroes of $f_j$ are contained in $N$ by definition. Since the zeroes of the $f_i$ generate $N'$, we must have $N' \subseteq N$.

---

The above proof is nowhere in my book. The issue as to why I'm seeking a different, easier proof is that, while proving a certain theorem in the book,  the author implicitly assumes $N' \subseteq N$, leading me to wonder if there is an intuitive, shorter explanation of said fact.

---

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I will use definition of normality as if $f\in K[x]$ irreducible admitting root in $S$, then $f$ splits linearly. Fix intermediate field $S$ between $M$ and $L$. Take $N'$ and $N$ as in your notation. Take a $f\in M[x]$ admitting a root $\alpha$ in $N'$. Since $M$ algebraic over $K$, you can find a polynomial $g\in K[x]$ irreducible with root $\alpha$. Note that $f\mid g$. In particular, you have all roots lying in $N$. Lower normal closure gives you something larger as you have more choice for coefficients.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805496/11619).

Comment: A simpler(?) argument is that an extension is normal if and only if it is a splitting field of a polynomial with coefficients in the smaller field. So we know that $N$ is a splitting field (over $K$) of a polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $K$. Because $K\subseteq L\subseteq N$, the big field $N$ is also a splitting field of $f$ over $L$. Trivially $f$ has coefficients in $L$, so we can deduce that $N/L$ is normal. By definition $N'$ is a minimal normal extension of $L$ containing $M$. We just saw that $N$ is a normal extension of $L$ containing $M$. Claim follows.

Comment: Well, it is actually your argument without explicit polynomials. Anyway, it does rely on the descsription of a normal closure (inside a suitable umbrella field such as an algebraic closure) as the intersectiion of all normal extensions. A number of details swept under the rug :-)

Comment: The reason why this may be glossed over in some texts is that the readers have seen other similar [closure operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) in action earlier. So in some sense it is *the same old*.